# Does the set of "bound factor" of linear operator always have an minimum?

Tags: banach-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

$\|T(u)\|\le M\|u\|$

T is a bounded operator between normed linear spaces, then is the set of all the "bound factor"(what is the proper name for this set?) M always have an minimum and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any set contained in $[0,\infty)$ has a finite infimum. What is more useful is the fact that the constants $M$ here have a mimimum. If $\|Tu \| \leq M_n \|u\|$ for all $u$ and $n$ and if $M_n \to M$ then $\|Tu \| \leq M \|u\|$ for all $u$. Hence the infimum is attained.

Details: Let $A=\{M \geq 0: \|Tu\|\leq M \|u\| \forall u\}$. Let $m=\inf A$. Then there exists a sequence $(M_n) \subset A$ such that $M_n \to m$. Since $\|Tu\|\leq M_n \|u\|$ for all $u$ and $n$ we can let $n \to \infty$ to get $\|Tu\| \leq m \|u\|$ for all $u$. Hence $m \in A$ and $m$ is the  minimum of $A$.

Comment: (1) But (0,...) doesn't have a infimum right? (2) Why Tu<=Mnu for all u and n and if Mn->M then Tu<=Mu? The detail is what is needed here (3) Can a series represent all element in the set?

Comment: $M$ can be $0$ too. For the zero operator we have $M=0$. @jw_

Comment: Get it now.....But "Any set contained in [0,∞) has a finite infimum" is wrong, right?

Comment: @jw_ You are not distinguishing between minimum and infimum. Infimum always exists. It is the minimum that need not exist. For example the infimum of $(0,\infty) $ exists and it is $0$. But it is not the minimum.

Comment: Got it before you complete the edit...sorry for my laziness to think, some of your precious time is wasted which could have been used to answer more questions if I thought before ask.

Comment: Yes that's another thing I learned by this post.